# SQL Server 2005 : Aborting query cause a deadlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

In a SQL Server 2005 with default configuration, read_committed isolation level and read_committed snapshot off. Could a query abort because of a deadlock? If so, why?

What about if I increase the isolation level to Repeatable reads?

According to msdn documents a situation like this is possible with any level of isolation :

```
Transaction T_1 acquires a share lock on row 1.
Transaction T_2 acquires a share lock on row 2.
Transaction T_1 now requests an exclusive lock on row 2 ( because it wants to change it), and is blocked until transaction T_2 finishes and releases the share lock it has on row 2.
Transaction T_2 now requests an exclusive lock on row 1 ( because it wants to change it), and is blocked until transaction T_1 finishes and releases the share lock it has on row 1.
```

Comment: Yes - with default isolation level, deadlocks are absolutely possible. And the more restrictive the isolation level, the longer the transactions and the locks they hold become - and thus the probability of deadlocks probably increases (but definitely doesn't decrease ..)

Comment: Can you be more precise? I have understood they can happen only if Both REPEATABLE READ and SERIALIZABLE are set. Because these configurations are the only which an exclusive lock.
Does DBMS use exclusive lock when the isolation level is read_commited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server uses several types of locks - if it **needs to write data** (e.g. insert new data or update existing rows), it will need to use an **exclusive lock - always, in any isolation level**.

With the fact that you have exclusive locks in play, there's always a chance of a deadlock - process A holds an exclusive lock on resource A and needs exclusive access to resource B, while another process B has the exclusive lock on resource B and wants access to resource A.

This can happen in **any isolation level** (even with `READ UNCOMMITTED`, SQL Server will take out exclusive locks for writing data!) and my point is: the more restrictive an isolation level is, the longer these locks tend to stick around, thus the higher the chance becomes that a deadlock can occur.

If you haven't already - you should be all means read, re-read, and re-re-read the following articles until you get a good understanding of the SQL Server locking mechanisms:

- [MSDN: Understanding Locking in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [Introduction to Locking in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server)
- [Understanding SQL Server Locking](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1968/understanding-sql-server-locking/)
- [Handling Deadlocks in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/handling-deadlocks-in-sql-server/)

Comment: thanks! So a situation such that I've inserted in my question is possible with any level of isolation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation for a general understanding of locks.

The only type of statement that does not acquire a lock is read uncommitted (dirty).
For that reason I use read uncommitted a lot.

A read committed does not take an exclusive lock but it does prevent an exclusive lock.
Could it cause a deadlock?
In theory it would not as the update could always just wait for the read committed lock to clear.
In real life if the query was very slow a waiting exclusive lock might time out but technically maybe not a dead lock.

So the query could abort because of a deadlock but I don't think the query could directly cause the deadlock.

If you have updates that could deadlock the presence of a lot of read locks would increase the chance of an update deadlock.  Consider a very very active table.  While update A is waiting for a readlock to clear on a page update B comes into play on the same page.   Update A and update B deadlock.  If update A was not waiting for the read lock to clear it would have been in and out.

Comment: "A read committed does not take an exclusive lock but it does prevent an exclusive lock" where there is written ?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?  -1  What do you think exclusive means?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=SQL.80).aspx  Exclusive (X) locks prevent access to a resource by concurrent transactions. No other transactions can read or modify data locked with an exclusive (X) lock.